# PHPMailer disable smtp backup

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using **PHPMailer** for send emails to my clients. I'm using SMTP connection. I want to only send email to client email address. But PHPMailer automatically saves email on my **Sent Mails** folder. I want to disable save emails on sent mails folder.

Is it possible? Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer doesn't do anything similar, and the base library can't either.

If you have a modified version, or your operating system's mailer saves everything in a folder.

Otherwise it worth a try to remove the 'Sent Mails' directory, or set its permissions to non-writable by anybody, or replace the folder by a file. Maybe any of these options helps.
These solutions are hacky... The clean way would be to turn of in the mail server's config/or in the phpmailer's modification you use.